# US Green card entry

Tags: immigration, greencard

I am US green card holder. I was in US last year, 2021. I had applied for reentry permit in June 2021 (Form I-131, Application for Travel Document) that allows one to stay outside US for upto 2 years. I had applied for it before leaving US last year. I got the application receipt and also biometric was waived. I left US after that around 29th July 2021. I am still abroad and the case status is still pending. I am about to complete 1 year.
Should I go back to US just to maintain my green card validity?
Or I need not travel to US, since the reentry permit will likely get approved soon.

Comment: I don't think there's much point in returning to the US if you're confident that the reentry permit will be issued.

Comment: Actually, I do not know what criteria they use to approve. I have a US job. But I have been working remotely since last year. Is it worth taking the risk and not travel just for this?

Comment: @phoog is there another portal where I can ask to get some help? Thanks.

Comment: Anyone has any suggestions here?

Comment: It's difficult to provide a useful answer without knowing more about your circumstances.  Why have you left the US, when do you plan to return; in short, what is your case for asserting that you haven't abandoned your residence in the US?  For how long would you return to the US if you went back "just to maintain" the green card?

Comment: Thanks @phoog for following up. Here is more about my circumstance: I am still single. I left US end of July last year because my company offices were closed. I was working from home. So, instead I came to stay with my parents in India. My company is fine with me working remotely from India and I am still on US payroll.

My plan is to return after I get married maybe later this year or earlier next year.

If I went back just to maintain green card, it would be a short trip, say for a week or two.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information.  The reason I'm not posting an answer is that I do not know whether a short trip like that would in fact reset the 1-year period after which your green card can't be used for reentry to the US.  Once the reentry permit is granted, of course, it no longer matters that the green card can't be used for reentry to the US.  In any event, being outside the US for more than a year does not by itself cause you to lose your LPR status, nor does it make the green card invalid for any other purpose.

Comment: Thanks @phoog. So there is no strict 1 year away rule that makes the green card invalid?

Comment: The green card remains valid but it can only be used in lieu of an immigrant visa [if seeking readmission after a temporary absence of less than 1 year](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/211.1).  On your second return to the US, an immigration officer might decide that your temporary trip to the US was insufficient to interrupt your temporary absence from the US, making the absence from the US longer than one year.  I have no idea how likely that is in practice; a US immigration lawyer probably would know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138058/discussion-between-nikhil-and-phoog).